# Animating two UserControls on the same ContentControl at the same time

Tags: wpf, rendertransform

I've these `Load` and `Unload` animations in `App.xaml`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Unload">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="-800"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="Load">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="800"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

In my code I'm calling those on Button Clicks like these:

```
sb1 = FindResource("Unload") as Storyboard;
sb2 = FindResource("Load") as Storyboard;

void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    uc1.RenderTransform = GetTG();
    uc2.RenderTransform = GetTG();

    sb1.Begin(uc2);
    sb2.Begin(uc1);

    content.Content = uc1;
}

//and 

void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    uc2.RenderTransform = GetTG();
    uc1.RenderTransform = GetTG();

    sb2.Begin(uc2);
    sb1.Begin(uc1);

    content.Content = uc2;
}
```

`GetTG` returns a `TransformGroup`

```
TransformGroup GetTG()
{
    var tg = new TransformGroup();
    tg.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform());
    tg.Children.Add(new SkewTransform());
    tg.Children.Add(new RotateTransform());
    tg.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform());
    return tg;
}
```

with these only the `Load` animation works. How to make both work at the same time?

Comment: If you are trying to show transitions when your content changes, then there are various Transitionals WPF libraries you can find when you google. They make the code as simple as setting TransitonalControl.Content, and the rest of the transition is handled by the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the animation to the `ContentControl`. This should slide out the current `Content`/`UserControl` to the left and slide in the new `Content`/`UserControl` from the right:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UnLoadAndLoad(uc1);
}

void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UnLoadAndLoad(uc2);
}

void UnLoadAndLoad(object ucToBeLoaded)
{
    if (content.Content != ucToBeLoaded)
    {
        content.RenderTransform = GetTG();

        EventHandler completed = null;
        completed = (ss, ee) =>
        {
            sb1.Completed -= completed;
            content.Content = ucToBeLoaded;
            //load
            sb2.Begin(content);
        };
        sb1.Completed += completed;
        //unload

        if (content.Content != null)
            sb1.Begin(content);
        else
            completed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: at this point `sb1.Completed += completed;` I get this error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Specified value of type 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard' must have IsFrozen set to false to modify.'`

Comment: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622513/error-using-staticresource-as-storyboard-for-a-visualtransition) if I add `x:Shared="False"` in storyboard in `App.xaml`, it works but not simultaneously! It unloads `uc1` first, content becomes empty (white) after unloading `uc1` and on empty content loading of `uc2` then begins and so on.